# What are the equations for the modeling?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

We have a system of spring-mass-spring-mass-spring-mass and required to write the motion equation of the described system.
[image: Pic]

If I apply hooke's law to the system I got the following :
[image: Pic2]

Are these the correct equation form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The movement equations can be derived from the Lagrangian $L = T - U$ with

$$
\cases{
U = m g \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\\
T =\frac 12 m\sum_{k=1}^n \dot x_k^2+\frac 12 k\sum_{k=1}^n(x_{k-1}-x_k)^2
}
$$

with $x_0 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

if you apply Newton's second law on $x_1,x_2,x_3$, you should get (with $l_0$ the caracterisitc length of the spring) (and neglecting gravity)  :

$$m\ddot{x_1}=-k(2x_1-x_2)\\m\ddot{x_2}=-k(2x_2-x_3)\\m\ddot{x_3}=-k(x_3-x_2-l_0) $$

Comment: You can consider motion around the static equilibrium, so that gravity is accounted for.